# Understanding groupJoin

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I do not fully understand this operator.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/groupjoin.md

How to understand those parts:

> Correlates the elements of two sequences based on overlapping durations, and groups the results.
>
> leftDurationSelector (Function): A function to select the duration (expressed as an observable sequence) of each element of the left observable sequence, used to determine overlap.
>   rightDurationSelector (Function): A function to select the duration (expressed as an observable sequence) of each element of the right observable sequence, used to determine overlap.

From the 4th argument:

> (Observable) An observable sequence with elements from the right sequence that overlap with the left sequence's element.

Why here 2nd and 3rd arguments are like this? What does timer(0) do good for us? I understand that timer(0) after 0 seconds returns value 0 and completes. So what?

```
var xs = Rx.Observable.interval(100)
    .map(function (x) { return 'first' + x; });

var ys = Rx.Observable.interval(100)
    .map(function (x) { return 'second' + x; });

var source = xs.groupJoin(
    ys,

    function () { return Rx.Observable.timer(0); },
    function () { return Rx.Observable.timer(0); },
    function (x, yy) {
        return yy.select(function (y) {
            return x + y;
        })
    }).mergeAll().take(5);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });
```

Maybe you know better source of explaination?

Answer (score 1):

Here are sources that you should review for a better understanding of `groupJoin`. By curiosity what do you aim to achieve by using this operator? There might be alternative ways to do the same. I have yet to come with an practical interesting use of `groupJoin`.

- [illustrated marble](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/join.html)
- [unit tests](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/tests/observable/groupjoin.js) (i.e. specifications, look speciialy the first one `GroupJoinOp_Normal_I`)
- [examples of usage](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc39)

I recommend you review these resources in order (and start by understanding `join`), and spend some time on the marble to understand what's going on.

About the official documentation example, `timer(0)` basically gives you duration selectors of one tick. The duration selector serves only as signals, their values is irrelevant to the output. When the duration selector emits a value or terminates, stuff happens (emission of grouped values from both streams). While they don't emit a value neither terminate, stuff happens too (grouping of values from both streams).

The selector function you pass receives the grouped values and computes other values from it. With `groupJoin`, that selector receives the value from the first source, and an observable which groups all the relevant values from the second source, and you do whatever logic you want with that.

Comment: I just try to understand this because I think it might be useful later when writing code with RxJS. Later will check those resources

Answer (score 0):

After user3743222 posted in answer, I took more time to understand from that page, I constantly check reactivex, but for this function it was hard to understand those arrows going from left to right with bit of angle.

There was mentioned windows. And it turns out that those arrows represent windows.

Second and third parameter is the window width:

```
 function () { return Rx.Observable.timer(500); }
```

For example above window width is 500 milliseconds (assuming that in this case we can measure width in time units).

I painted a graphic which looks for me more like windows:

[image]

So from my graph we can see for example that black window intersects with green window and so the events are joined by function in 4th parameter.

Same with green and red.

I did not investigate other cases, like what happens if more than one event from first stream windows intersect with 2nd stream, but at least we have an idea how it works, and maybe someone else will add info if there is some unexpected cases.

Also needs further investigation window widths of 0, because visually looking they do not exist, I mean if there is a window, I imagine it having width > 0.